Point Light and PointLightHelper Not Visible in Three.js Scene with Angular
I'm working on an Angular project where I'm incorporating a Three.js scene. My scene includes a torus, a point light, and a PointLightHelper to visualize the point light's position. Although the torus is correctly illuminated by an ambient light I added for troubleshooting, my point light and its helper are not having the expected visible effect on the scene.
Here's a summary of my setup:
I've positioned my point light close to the torus to ensure it should affect it.
I've added a PointLightHelper to visualize the point light's position.
An ambient light is added to the scene, making the torus visible.
A GridHelper is also added to understand the spatial relationships better.
However, despite these configurations, the point light and PointLightHelper don't seem to be visible or affecting the torus as expected.
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrl: ['./canvas.component.css']
})
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('bgCanvas') private canvasRef!: ElementRef;

  private camera!: THREE.Camera;
  private scene!: THREE.Scene;
  private renderer!: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  private torus!: THREE.Mesh;

  constructor() {
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initThree();
    this.animate();
  }

  private initThree() {
    // Scene setup
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: this.canvasRef.nativeElement});
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.camera.position.setZ(30);

    // Torus setup
    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(20,3,16,100);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xFF5347});
    this.torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.scene.add(this.torus);

    // Point light setup
    const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
    this.scene.add(pointLight);

    // PointLightHelper setup
    const pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight, 1);
    this.scene.add(pointLightHelper);

    // Ambient light setup
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    this.scene.add(ambientLight);

    // Render
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  private animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    this.torus.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.torus.rotation.y += 0.005;
    this.torus.rotation.z += 0.01;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}


I expected the point light to illuminate the torus and the PointLightHelper to be visible, indicating the position of the point light. However, the scene renders with the torus illuminated by the ambient light only, with no visible effect or visualization from the point light and its helper.
Attempts to fix:
I've tried changing the point light's position and intensity.
Added an ambient light to ensure other lighting works.
Used a GridHelper to better understand the scene's layout.
Questions:
Why might the point light and PointLightHelper not be visible or affecting the scene as expected?
Is there any additional setup required for the point light or its helper to work correctly in an Angular environment with Three.js?
